# Oracle SQL error: maximum number of expressions

Tags: sql, oracle

Could you please help me regarding that issue getting error in Oracle SQL

> ORA-01795 maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

I'm passing value like

```
and test in (1, 2, 3.....1000)
```

Comment: try passing it like `and test between 1 and 1000` (that is, if the values are all consecutive) or `and test >= 1 and test <= 1000`. See if that works.

Comment: [Did you research this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=ora-01795)

Comment: Put all those values in a temporary table instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split your query with multiple in clauses like below

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE test IN (1,2,3,....500) 
     OR test IN (501, 502, ......1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try workarounds:

Split single `in` into several ones:

```
   select ...
     from ...
    where test in (1, ...,  999) or 
          test in (1000, ..., 1999) or
          ...  
          test in (9000, ..., 9999)
```

Put values into a (temporary?) table, say `TestTable`:

```
   select ...
     from ...
    where test in (select TestField 
                     from TestTable)
```

**Edit:** As I can see, the main difficulty is to *build* such a query. Let's implement it in **C#**. We are given a collection of `id`s:

```
// Test case ids are in [1..43] range 
IEnumerable<int> Ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 43);

// Test case: 7, in actual Oracle query you, probably set it to 100 or 1000
int chunkSize = 7;

string fieldName = "test";

string filterText = string.Join(" or " + Environment.NewLine, Ids
  .Select((value, index) => new {
    value = value,
    index = index
  })
  .GroupBy(item => item.index / chunkSize)
  .Select(chunk => 
     $"{fieldName} in ({string.Join(", ", chunk.Select(item => item.value))})"));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterText))
  filterText = $"and \r\n({filterText})";

string sql =
  $@"select MyField
       from MyTable
      where (1 = 1) {filterText}";
```

Test:

```
Console.Write(sql);
```

Outcome:

```
select MyField
             from MyTable
            where (1 = 1) and 
(test in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) or 
test in (8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14) or 
test in (15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21) or 
test in (22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28) or 
test in (29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35) or 
test in (36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42) or 
test in (43))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i cnt break in like (1...999) as its passing from vb dynamically & also I cannot create a temporary table for it.Please suggest me other soultion. Thanks

Comment: And also ID which is generated dynamically so i can not keep condition like  test <= 1000